# Using a locally defined class instead of the one provided by a library/package C# IL Weaving

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, fody, intermediate-language

I have seen stuff like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and in fact have been using [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which reduces the boilerplate code after implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I believe it is done by 'weaving the IL' so an idea crossed my mind.

The problem is that I am trying to define my own version of a class and use it instead of the one defined in a nuget package. This is because the library one deals with a TextView whereas I would like it to deal with an AppCompatTextView instead.

AppCompatTextView is:

```
public class AppCompatTextView : 
    TextView,
    IEmojiCompatConfigurationView,
    IJavaObject,
    IDisposable,
    IJavaPeerable,
    ITintableBackgroundView,
    IAutoSizeableTextView,
    ITintableCompoundDrawablesView
```

As you can see, AppCompatTextView inherits from TextView and this should make things easier.

By default, the library (Xamarin.Forms) has defined a LabelRenderer as:

```
public class LabelRenderer : FormsTextView, IVisualElementRenderer, IViewRenderer, ITabStop
```

Where:

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
{
    public class FormsTextView : TextView
    {
        public FormsTextView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public FormsTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public FormsTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
        }

        [Obsolete]
        protected FormsTextView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public void SkipNextInvalidate()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to create my own version of LabelRenderer which inherits from AppCompatTextView instead.

This is to meet the requirements outlined by [Google to display modern emojis](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji2#custom-views-appcompat)

When seeing the code for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.LabelRenderer, we can see that:

```
protected global::Android.Widget.TextView Control => this;
```

The idea that came to my mind was that would it be possible to use some IL Weaving tool so that it would be this instead:

```
protected global::AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView Control => this;
```

In other words, would it be possible to 'weave the IL' in a way that when it wants to load this IL:

```
  .property instance class [Mono.Android]Android.Widget.TextView Control()
  {
    .get instance class [Mono.Android]Android.Widget.TextView Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.LabelRenderer::get_Control()
  }
```

It should be an AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView instead of Android.Widget.TextView:

```
.property instance class [Mono.Android]AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView Control()
  {
    .get instance class [Mono.Android]AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.LabelRenderer::get_Control()
  } // end of property LabelRenderer::Control
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Whether it is practical or advisable is another matter.

Comment: I don't see why not, on the face of it. Whether it would break anything else in the process I can't say. You probably want something you can run as a command-line app, rather than as an MSBuild task. I've had a quick scan through the Fody docs and can't find anything about that. It might be easier to use Mono.Cecil directly: this is the library which Fody uses under the hood.